# SQL Database Tracking Method

Tags: sql

I am building a database in SQL developer and am trying to figure out how to integrate tracking customer orders in my database. It would only need to know where the order is at any time during shipping. Any ideas? I am looking for  the very basic way for it is only for a class.

Comment: What tables do you have so far? I would guess at a minimum you'll need `customers`, `products`, `orders`, and `shipments`. Each row in the orders tables should have keys pointing back to which customer placed the order, who it was shipped with, what products were in the order, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a high level, you will need to represent the customer and the order. In most cases, orders have line items.

To track where the order is in the process, the simplest way to do that is to have a stat field. The status is changed over time. One step better would be to track the changes of the status in a OrderStatusHistory or something of that sort.

Here is a sample ERD without any fluff:

[image: Basic ERD]